# Vim and Paredit - why does line break push closing parenthesis to next line?

Tags: vim, clojure

I'm using vim to edit Clojure with [paredit.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim) and am noticing what I can't imagine is expected behaviour: when doing a simple line break, the closing parenthesis is always pushed to the next line, for example:

```
(if true
  "hello"
  )
```

instead of what I would expect:

```
(if true
  "hello")
```

A screencap video: http://d.pr/v/14S8F/4Z8gkHOA

I've disabled all other plugins other than `vundle` and `paredit.vim` to be safe, and it is occurring. I am using `vim 7.4` and also `macvim 7.4` with the same results.

Am I mistaken or is this the intended behaviour of paredit?

**edit**

While the selected answer does set the functionality I expected, the comment from @amalloy does indeed answer that this is paredit's intended functionality, and in `:help paredit` it does clarify this:

> If g:paredit_electric_return is on then it also re-gathers electric returns when appropriate.

and further:

> If nonzero then "electric return" feature is enabled. This means that when an
>    is pressed before a closing paren in insert mode, paredit will actually
>   insert two newlines creating an empty line. The extra newline is consumed at
>   pressing the next closing paren. This feature allows linewise editing of the
>   subform entered in the next (empty) line.
>   In other words  "opens" parenthetical expressions while editing, ')'
>   "closes" them.
>   Please note that electric return is disabled for the REPL buffer if Slimv
>   option |g:slimv_repl_simple_eval| is nonzero. In this case  is used
>   to send the command line to the swank server for evaluation.

Comment: Have you tried with forms other than `if`? eg, some made-up nonsense like `foo`. paredit.vim may be predicting that your `if` will have two branches, and therefore allocate two lines for you.

Comment: ah, that was a logical possibility, but it is still doing it even with just a `foo`: https://d.pr/v/1lO3V/4ycJhsVW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable [electric return](https://github.com/vim-scripts/paredit.vim/blob/master/doc/paredit.txt#L402-L412):

```
:let g:paredit_electric_return=0
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly the issue

Comment: Actually are you sure you want to disable this feature? If, like paredit on emacs, pressing `)` bounces the paren back to the right place, the extra space before the trailing paren may just be an editing convenience that fixes itself up when you're done with it.

Comment: Ah I see now, also interesting. That does also work as mentioned. I suppose I'll have to see how it feels as I spend more time with it. For anyone who is interested, here is another video: http://d.pr/v/3KM/2nFs3NU7

However, as mentioned above, this was the behaviour I initially expected